# JSF List of Values Options

Tags: java, jsf

I am using JSF 1.1 and I'm looking for a JSF list of values component.

I have a button and when I click that a popup window should open with one text field and buttons, where either I could search for what I am looking for in the text field or select all the values when I click on the buttons and from the available list of values I should be able to select one item.

Is any such type of component available in JSF 1.1 or with the icefaces, richfaces or apache jsf components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title is a little bit confusing, as you don't seem to ask for just a "list of values"-component, but a bunch of different components. Your situation is too specific to have a single existing component covering it all, but you can rather easily achieve the effect by combining a number of components.

Anyway, RichFaces has a [modalPanel](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html) that you can use for the popup. Text fields and buttons are in the standard Faces library and the 'available list of values` can be handled by a [selectOneMenu](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/selectOneMenu.html) component, which is also in the standard library.

One additional hint, if it's in anyway possible try not to use JSF 1.1. This is an extremely old version where the list of problems is nearly endless. If you are somehow stuck on a very servlet container you should at least use JSF 1.2, but **much** better is to use the latest 2.1 release.

Comment: I will try to use modalPanel and selectOneMenu. I cannot use higher version other than 1.1 as my apps server is little primitive! Thanks for the answer.